# Issue adding target rule to eventbridge bus in cdk

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have an eventBridge bus in my infrastructure and in a CDK will create a lambda and then would need to add such lambda as a target to the already existent bus rule to allow the bus to trigger the lambda.

So, what I am doing is this (parameters are valid in my real code):

```
// Import the existing EventBridge rule using its ARN
const existingRule = events.Rule.fromRuleArn(this, 'ExistingEventBridgeRule', 'arn:aws:events:<region>:<account>:rule/<rule-name>');

    // Add the Lambda function as a target to the existing rule
    existingRule.addTarget(new targets.LambdaFunction(myLambda));
```

When I try to bootstrap I receive the error: "addTarget is not a function".The error is driving me nuts as this way to add the target is present in all the examples I saw and have no idea why I am receiving the error.

What am I doing wrong?Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CDK cannot modify external resources. If you look at the [signature of `fromRuleArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html#static-fromwbreventwbrrulewbrarnscope-id-eventrulearn), you will see that it returns an instance of [`IRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.IRule.html), not [`Rule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html). This represents the fact that it is simply a read-only reference to an existing resource, not a resource you can modify.

You can see that `IRule` indeed does not have a `addTarget` method, since it is a read-only reference.